# git repository tracking files from another local repository

Tags: git, github

I created a new remote repo using files from a local rep (repo is called red). For some reason red is tracking a file from `midas`, a completely different repo. I tried deleting everything and starting from scratch and it's still tracking this file from `midas`.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1I1y.png]

I see it says "use git checkout file" to discard changes, but I'm new to git and nervous about what will happen

Comment: Is `code` a repository (has a `.git` directory) too?

Answer (score 1):

A folder (like midas) with "new commits" associated to its status means it is a **[git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** (checkout if you have a `../.gitmodules` files)

If it is, you can remove that submodule if you don't need it.
See [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309).

Note that your main repo is in `~jenminervas/code` and *not* in `~jenminervas/code/red`.
If that is not what you want, you should delete (or at least rename) `~jenminervas/code/.git`.